# Adding ToC line manually within appendix

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to manually add the `chapters` of my appendix to the ToC, but the result is horrible. The page number is placed directly next to the chapter name, instead of using the regular format where the page number aligns right.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[toc,page,title]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Week 1 - Intro \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}}}
\begin{appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A} 
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\chapter{\large{\textbf{Appendix A - \textcolor{blue}{R} commando's}}} \\
\chapter{\large{\textbf{Appendix B - Begrippenlijst}}}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot of the code:

[image: Screenshot]

So what I want is to have the "regular" ToC format when adding these chapters to the ToC. All manuals I can find offer no explanation as to how the `\addcontentsline` command works, but I'm almost certain the solution lies in that command, specifically in the "entry" part of the command (third argument).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `article` class and using `\chapter` which doesn't look correct. Use `\section` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[toc,page,title]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Week 1 - Intro \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}}}
\begin{appendices}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix A}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\section{Appendix A - \protect\textcolor{blue}{R} commando's}
\section{Appendix B - Begrippenlijst}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have removed extra commands from the section arguments and modified. Note the `\protect` since `\textcolor` is fragile..

Further, you need not add `Appendix A` in the section title. Use `titletoc` option for `appendix`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[titletoc,page,title]{appendix}   %% note titletoc

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Week 1 - Intro \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{R}}}
\begin{appendices}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix A}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\section{\protect\textcolor{blue}{R} commando's}
\section{Begrippenlijst}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]